# Facebook API dosen't work in release mode

Tags: android, facebook, key, release

I'm trying to integrate Facebook API support into my application. It works fine with a debug key. I'm using following command:

`keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

But when I try to use a release key, it doesn't work; I can't post on the wall.

Any ideas?

Comment: What error are you getting, and why do you think it's linked to the key you're using to sign the app?

Comment: well when I use the debug key, everything workes fine, but when I use the key string that got from release keystore then application just not works, just not posting, like nothing happened

Comment: and one more thing, I changed the key in facebook application from debug key to release, but I'm still able to do post with debug key version of my android application

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the release key to your [app dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) on Facebook?  Make sure that the keys that you use for developing the app are in the "Android Key Hash" section of the app's basic settings.

Comment: I would recommend enabling logging on our Android SDK by setting `ENABLE_LOG` in `Util.java` to be true, so that when it fails it should print out the key that its using (look for an entry that says "Android key mismatch"), and you should verify that its the same key in the dashboard.

Comment: Also, any logcat or error messages that you can show would be really helpful as well.